# Each year in range apply to array

Tags: php

I got this code:

```
/**
 * Transforms field value to readable text for listing.
 *
 * @param string $fieldName
 * @param Entity_Topic $entity
 * @return string
 */
public function presenter($fieldName, *** $entity) {
  $years = range(2014, 2020);
    if ('dateFrom' == $fieldName) {
      foreach($years as $year) {
        $list = array(
            $year.'-01-01' => 'Leden '.$year,
            $year.'-02-01' => 'Únor '.$year,
            $year.'-03-01' => 'Březen '.$year,
            $year.'-04-01' => 'Duben '.$year,
            $year.'-05-01' => 'Květen '.$year,
            $year.'-06-01' => 'Červen '.$year,
            $year.'-07-01' => 'Červenec '.$year,
            $year.'-08-01' => 'Srpen '.$year,
            $year.'-09-01' => 'Září '.$year,
            $year.'-10-01' => 'Říjen '.$year,
            $year.'-11-01' => 'Listopad '.$year,
            $year.'-12-01' => 'Prosinec '.$year,
        );
        return $list[$entity->getDateFrom()];
      }
    }
    return '';
}
```

This code shows only data for 2014 year, other years are just null. Any ideas how to make it work correctly so it can show other years too?

```
if ('dateFrom' == $fieldName) {
          foreach($years as $year) {
            $list = array(
                   ***
            );
          }
  return $list[$entity->getDateFrom()];
}
```

This is not working..

Comment: Your `return` is inside the `foreach` loop (this means that after the first loop - the data will return. the loop will not continue to the next values). You should build the data inside the `foreach` loop, and `return` the data **after** the `foreach (..) { ..}` block.

Comment: It's impossible to understand code in comments.

Comment: You're overwriting `$list` in each iteration of `foreach` loop, fix that.

Comment: I've added fixed code, but still not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fixed one problem but one more issue is still left. You're overwriting `$list` in each iteration of `foreach` loop. And even if you do `$list[] = array(...`, the problem won't go away because your end purpose is to fetch appropriate data from this array as well. Hence, change your `presenter()` method in the following way,

```
public function presenter($fieldName, $entity) {
    $years = range(2014, 2020);
    if ('dateFrom' == $fieldName) {
        $years = range(2014, 2020);
        $months = array('Leden', 'Únor', 'Březen', 'Duben', 'Květen', 'Červen', 'Červenec', 'Srpen', 'Září', 'Říjen', 'Listopad', 'Prosinec');
        $list = array();
        foreach($years as $year){
            for($i = 1; $i <= 12; ++$i){
                $list[$year . '-' . $i . '-01'] = $months[$i - 1] . ' ' . $year;
            }
        }
        return $list[$entity->getDateFrom()];
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: for($i = 01; $i <= 12; ++$i){
    $list[$year . '-' . $i . '-01'] = $months[$i - 1] . ' ' . $year;
} This is how it works. Thanks for direction :)

Comment: @ElmarBabayev I believe `for($i = 1; ...` would also work, I've updated my answer.

Comment: you are right. btw it wasn't working even with $i = 01 for months like 1-9, so I had to change my dateFormat from 'yy-mm-dd' to 'yy-m-dd' and now it's perfect.